# Ionic 3 build with --minifyjs flag get stucks on first load of app only in iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, minify, production-environment

I have an **Ionic 3** app that runs well in **Android** and **iOS** without the **--prod** flag. Now I want to test the **App** in **production mode** in **iOS** and **Android**.

When I try to run it on **Android** everything works great! and a little bit faster and smoother. Now I try to run it on **iOS** which it doesn't work. It gets stuck on the first load of the **App** on the **Splashscreen**. At first I expect that there is something wrong in my **plugins** or **versions compatibility of my plugin**s and to the **version** of the **iOS device**.

But I was wrong I try to run it without the **--uglifyjs**, **--minifycss**, **-aot**, **--optimizejs** and it works, the app didn't get stuck at the first booth or first load. All these flags are part of the **--prod** flag right? But you notice that I didn't include **--minifyjs** in the flag. Because when I try to run it on **--minifyjs** the problem occurs again when it got stucks on the first load of the app.

I have also reference to my old question: [Ionic cordova run ios --prod gets stuck on splash screen loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228381/ionic-cordova-run-ios-prod-gets-stuck-on-splash-screen-loader?noredirect=1#comment95294017_54228381) but that wasn't the problem anymore. It only happens when I try to use the **--minifyjs** flag.

Here is my **ionic info**:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v8.9.3
    npm        : 5.5.1
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

So what can be the problem with that? I think it is more of a compiling issue of minifying js files by **angular and ionic** by reducing its size. I think it affects some of the js files that caused the problem.

Appreciate if someone could help. Thanks in advance.